# Unknown Compute Traffic

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

Yesterday around 6pm I started seeing some new Compute traffic in my Dashboard that has continued to this morning. The Traffic does not originate from any service I've created as my project is pretty small so I would know. it also appears the traffic has a 100% error rate. Here is a screenshot from my Dashboard.

[image]

I'm mostly wondering if this something I should be worried about or if there are steps I can take to stop this traffic that I should take. Thanks for any ideas.

Comment: In the API metrics page, there is an option to graph the traffic by API method, credential and more. That might help you narrow down in figuring out the source of the requests.

Answer (score 0):

In your Google Cloud Console, when you are on the home page on the dashboard view, you should be able to see a card that indicates the current running resources in your project, if you have active compute instances you will see them there. If you click on it it will take you to the Compute instance page, and from there you will be able to manage your compute instances.